# Special Characters and Searches with Laravel elequant

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The issue I am having is with Special Characters. Search with the inputs %(Modular), __(_Underscore), O(Number). It will not filter out any result. it will display all the results. Where as searching templates having other special characters and number displaying correct results.

If in the DB I have subject of myname is % user, and the users search input is %, it doesn't find the result. Same with__(_Underscore), O(Number).

```js
($searchkeyword) {
                    $q->where(function($query) use ($searchkeyword) {
                        $query->where('studentname', 'like', "%$searchkeyword%")
                        ->orWhere('subject', 'like', "%$searchkeyword%")
                        ->orWhere('city', 'like', "%$searchkeyword%");
                    });
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `%` in your search keyword. I don't know why `_` and `0` is not working in your case, but maybe you need to escape them as well.

In MySQL, you'd need to use `[%]`. So maybe in your case, the query could work if you do a `str_replace` beforehand.

```php
$searchkeyword = str_replace('%', '[%]', $searchkeyword);

// query
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
($searchkeyword) {
    $q->where(function($query) use ($searchkeyword) {
        $query->where('studentname', 'like', "%$searchkeyword%")
        ->orWhere('subject', 'like', "%$searchkeyword%")
        ->orWhere('city', 'like', "%$searchkeyword%");
    });
})
```

to

```
$searchkeyword = (string)$searchkeyword;
($searchkeyword) {
    $q->where(function($query) use ($searchkeyword) {
        $query->where('studentname', 'like', "%".$searchkeyword."%")
        ->orWhere('subject', 'like', "%".$searchkeyword."%")
        ->orWhere('city', 'like', "%".$searchkeyword."%");
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code,

```
$students = Student::all();

$students->where(function($query) use($searchkeyword) {
     $query->where('studentname', 'like', '%' . $searchkeyword . '%')
     ->orWhere('subject', 'like', '%' . $searchkeyword . '%')
     ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%' . $searchkeyword . '%')
});
```